# Python function - Are variables copied or referenced? Best practice?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, function, copy, deep-copy

When I create a pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(...)
```

and give it to some function:

```
def func1(data):
   ax = data
   ax[:] = 1
   return ax
```

Which I then call with:

```
func(df)
df
```

This returns the dataframe df with all values "1", so there is no local copy made of the variable of the function but rather a reference with `ax=data` which points at df.

Is there a best practice to make copy? Like calling `func(df.deepcopy(True)`)? Or would
you rather set `ax = data.deepcopy(True)` or this there even a better more efficient/intuitive way?